# Reduce computer prices by 20 percent and also all products with more than 4 offers

Tags: sql-server

I need to "Reduce computer prices by 20 percent and also all products with more than 4 offers"

I have the following query and the math comes out wrong but is similar to the output.

```
SELECT 
    o.supp_id, p.prod_id, 
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(o.price * .80), 3) AS FLOAT) as 'Price', 
    o.Quantity
FROM
    tb_product p, tb_offers o
WHERE 
    p.name = 'computer'
    AND p.prod_ID = o.prod_ID
GROUP BY
    o.supp_id, p.prod_ID, quantity

UNION

SELECT 
    supp_id, p.prod_id, 
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(tb_offers.price * .80), 3) AS FLOAT) as 'Price', 
    Quantity
FROM 
    tb_product p, tb_offers
WHERE 
    tb_offers.prod_id = p.prod_ID
GROUP BY 
    tb_offers.supp_id, p.prod_id, quantity
HAVING 
    COUNT(p.prod_Id) > 4
```

The query above the union works out, but the one on bottom doesn't return anything (which should be the products with more more than 4 offers.

Is the bottom query showing me the products with more than 4 offers?

I have the following tables:

```
Tb_Consumer - Name, City, Con_ID 
Tb_Supplier - Name, City, Supp_ID 
Tb_Offers - Name, Quantity, Prod_ID, Supp_ID 
Tb_Product - Name, Prod_ID 
Tb_Requests - Name, Quantity, Prod_ID, Con_ID 
Tb_Transactions- Tran_ID, Supp_ID, Con_ID, Quantity, Price
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

If you are only changing prices why are you summing up the results ? I think you need to do something like....

```
SELECT    o.supp_id
        , p.prod_id
        , CAST( (o.price * 0.80)   AS DECIMAL(18,3)) as [Price]
        , o.Quantity
FROM tb_product p
INNER JOIN  tb_offers o ON p.prod_ID = o.prod_ID
WHERE p.name = 'computer'
OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
            FROM tb_product p1
            WHERE p.prod_ID = p1.prod_ID
            HAVING COUNT(p1.prod_Id) > 4
           )
```